# Installing a temperature probe... what kind of adhesive to use?

Tags: creality-ender-3, hotend

I am trying to install a new Dragonfly hotend on my Ender 3.

I bought some epoxy which advertised high thermal conductivity, but I've found it difficult to use.  It was thick, so it was very hard for me to get the very thin probe ends into the relatively large hole filled with epoxy, especially if I want to be careful of air gaps (which I have no way of checking for.)

The problem was so bad I actually bought a new hotend.  What materials or techniques can you suggest to get the probe installed faithfully?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to use an adhesive? Generally they are screwed in or on, if you are using a glass bead you could consider thermal paste. But this heater block needs a thermistor using a 3 mm metal cartridge/shell. So please update the question and preferably add images.

Comment: the *standard* these days is a metal cartridge, glass thermosensors are very fragile.

Comment: Don't forget that everything is relative.  In addition to high conductivity to the item you wish to measure, you can aim for low heat transfer to everything else.  This is achieved via insulation.  That means if you have a simple metal contact, you can then goop insulative adhesive behind it all as long as the goop does not come in between.  This can have the additional benefit of increased efficiency from the additional insulation.